# adding consecutive value of rainfall in R according to date

Tags: r

I have a dataset named "Dhaka" that looks like below:

1. time     precipitation
2. 01/01/1998   5
3. 01/02/1998   2
4. 01/03/1998   4
5. 01/04/1998   6
6. 01/05/1998   7
7. 01/06/1998   11

I want to do the consecutive summation of the precipitation in a way so that it sums the precipitation of the three days (precipitation of two days before the exact date+ exact date precipitation).
The output may look like below:

1. time precipitation
2. 01/01/1998   5
3. 01/02/1998   7 = 5+2
4. 01/03/1998   11 =5+2+4
5. 01/04/1998   12 =2+4+6
6. 01/05/1998   17 = 4+6+7
7. 01/06/1998   24 = 6+7+11

the first value will be the same, second value will be the sum of the first and second value and the rest will be the summation of three precipitation value. I used

`rollapply(precipitation, 3, sum)`

but it did not give value date wise.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is cumsum:

```
library(data.table)
Dhaka <- data.table(Dhaka)[order(time)]

totalSum <- Dhaka[, cumsum(precipitation)]
```

Take the difference:

```
diffSum <- diff(totalSum, lag = 3)
finalSum <- c(totalSum[1:3], diffSum)

Dhaka[, sums := finalSum]
```

Comment: The rationale here is that the sum of any three sequential numbers is the difference between the cumulative sum at the two respective times, t and t+3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. Instead of getting summation value day wise, i am getting it monthwise (01/01/1998, THEN 01/01/1999, 01/01/2000) in this way. I want it in this way: 01/01/1998, 01/02/1998, 01/03/1998). Could you please help me in this manner? Again thanks a lot.